# Set first element of colormap in matplotlib to gray

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I change the first color in a listed colormap in matplotlib to gray? I created the colormap as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.get_cmap('viridis_r')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I haven't tested this, but does this work?

```
>>> col_map = plt.get_cmap('viridis_r')
>>> col_map.__dict__['colors'].insert(0,[0.5,0.5,0.5])
```